# Azure Table Storage - Query timestamp

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage

I have probably dumb question, but I've been struggling with it for several hours and it bothers me. I want to receive records that appeared in the last 6 hours.

The problem is the date formatting - I can't pass the time in the custom filter, every version I tried returns an empty record. The filter only works for dates in the format 'yyyy-MM-dd'. I have already checked toString ('s), various date formats (yyyy-MM-ddThh: mm e.g). What is the correct date and time format in the filter?

```
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant "" 

$storageResourceGroup = ""
$storageAccount = ""
$tableName = ""

$AppName = ""
$AppResourceGroup = ""

$date  = (Get-Date).AddHours(-6).toString('yyyy-MM-dd') 

$table = Get-AzTableTable -resourceGroup $storageResourceGroup -TableName $tableName -storageAccountName $storageAccount

$records = Get-AzTableRow -Table $table -customFilter "(Timestamp gt datetime'$date')" //How to filter with time???

$records.TableTimestamp

$date
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? or no results?

Comment: @GauravMantri Nevermind, toString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:MM:ssZ') working perfectly ;)

Answer (score 0):

toString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ') working perfectly (HH for 24h format)